# Is apigee proxy implementation with sweet lime easy?

Tags: xml, proxy, apigee

I am new to Apigee, from db background. I have created already two proxys. There is a lot of policies and flow, a bit overwhelming i feel. So I make a search on internet and I now see this. 
http://beatzone.cz/component/video/W-WDjIkeDcs

Is it easy to develop with sweet lime? is there any more docu on this? I don't see many information on your docu http://apigee.com/docs/search/site/sweetlime.
Additionally, do I also need to buy sweet lime? or is it free with apogee edge?

note: please mark duplicate if asked before.

Answer (score 2):

Apigee sweetlime is a free plugin for an editor called sublime text3, which can be downloaded from here - http://www.sublimetext.com/3. It is available as a trial version as well as a paid one.

Sweetlime makes proxy development on sublime text really easy as you can now add a policy template, add a new step definition, add a flow etc with just a click.Its one of the great ways to do proxy development without using the UI. Some of the many benefits of development through an editor is that you can maintain a development workspace and do source code management. You can also add comments to your XML code (UI strips off the comments) and make it more readable. Sublime and sweetlime together is an awesome way of managing big projects.

Sweetlime is an open source project which is definitely going to enhance as we at Apigee and our developer community adds more features to it.

Comment: thank you, sweet lime is parallel to eclipse plugin, all right. Now i buy sublime text to use sweet lime? does sweet lime expires with expire of sublimetext trial?

also apigee docu does not have information about sweet lime. Where do I find information or guide to use it?

Comment: Actually, the UI does not strip comments - that bug was fixed several months ago.